# Django "get" method not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a single row from my database using the "get" method in Python/Django. The model I'm using is

```
class SavedQuery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    queryText = models.CharField(max_length = 2048)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, I've saved some values in that database, ensuring that all of them are unique. So now I want to get the value of the queryText when given a name. I tried using the following code:

```
    entry = SavedQuery.objects.get(name = query_name) 
    #query_name is an input to the function, and I've verified it is correct
```

The line for entry, however, does not work. I'm getting a 500 error through the browser, and the terminal I'm running the server from isn't showing any error message. The DEBUG output is incomprehensible to me as well.

My band-aid solution is to use SavedQuery.objects.all() and then go through and check the name field, but I have seen on the Django site that it's possible to get a list of objects with a certain value in a given field, so I'd rather just do that.

EDIT: Debugging output from the spot where it's messing up is

```
2014-06-12 19:56:20 DEBUG    bolt django.db.backends util.execute:79: (0.000) SELECT `bolt_savedquery`.`id`, `bolt_savedquery`.`name`, `bolt_savedquery`.`queryText`, `bolt_savedquery`.`created` FROM `bolt_savedquery` WHERE `bolt_savedquery`.`name` = 'Kyle' ; args=(u'Kyle',)
2014-06-12 19:56:20 DEBUG    bolt django.db.backends util.execute:79: (0.000) SELECT `bolt_savedquery`.`id`, `bolt_savedquery`.`name`, `bolt_savedquery`.`queryText`, `bolt_savedquery`.`created` FROM `bolt_savedquery` LIMIT 21; args=()
```

Comment: There has to be some error. Can't help without traceback or error. Does `.get` raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` or `ObjectDoesNotExist` or something?

Comment: Additionally, during development, I encourage you to set `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py` file.  That way you will see tracebacks in the browser rather than a 500 error...

Comment: I had DEBUG enabled, but then I couldn't even find my print debugging within all the other debugging output, and it didn't make sense to me, so I wasn't using it.

Comment: And what is displayed on the webpage when the error occured? You shull have a full page with the exception raised and a complete traceback.

Comment: I get multiple objects returned. I think I accidentally had a duplicate in there during testing, so perhaps that is why.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comments, you're having a `SavedQuery.MultipleObjectsReturned` error raised. You'll need to either make the `name` field a unique field so you know you'll only get one result back when using `SavedQuery.objects.get()` or you can do something like `SavedQuery.objects.filter(name=VALUE).first()`. You could also use `.last()` to get the most recently created one.